# My javascript Async Await api request returns a strange object

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await

I'm making an API request with [Frisbee](https://github.com/niftylettuce/frisbee):

```
const Frisbee = require('frisbee')

const api = new Frisbee({
  baseURI: 'http://192.168.1.8:4000',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
})

export const handleSubmit = async (values): void => {
  Toast.show('Uploading Product', {
    duration: 3000,
    position: 30,
    shadow: true,
    animation: true,
    hideOnPress: true,
    delay: 0
  })

  try {
    const response = api.post('/products', {
      body: encodeAddProductAction(values)
    })
    if (response.err) throw response.err
    console.log(response)
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
}

export const encodeAddProductAction = (values: any) => {
  const submitPayload = Object.assign({}, values)
  Object.keys(submitPayload).forEach((key) => {
    if (key != 'Categories') {
      submitPayload[key] = encodeURIComponent(
        JSON.stringify(submitPayload[key])
      )
    } else {
      // values[key] = JSON.stringify(values[key])
      submitPayload[key] = submitPayload[key].join(',')
    }
  })

  return submitPayload
}
```

It console logs this:

[image]

Why is my API response body buried in some strange fields like `_55`?

My response is:

[image]

Comment: You titled this "async await problem", but you're not using `await`. That's why it's returning the promise instead of the response.

Comment: `const response = await api.post(...)`

Comment: @Barmar Got it. Thanks

Comment: @Barmar So the numbers come from the frisbee library 40, 60, 55, do you know what is the reason for using those specific numbers in a promise?

Comment: No idea, it's just some internal data that you don't need to worry about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `async` but you are not `await`ing response, that's why you get Promise returned.

```
 try {
    const response = await api.post('/products', {
      body: encodeAddProductAction(values)
    })
    if (response.err) throw response.err
    console.log(response)
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
```

`Async` by default returns a `Promise`.

Comment: Thank you. Accepting when it'll allow me.